# Change and Access value of Python2.7 Dict Element

Tags: python, json

I am trying to modify a Python dict value. I think it may be to nested.

I tried:

```
for x in annotations:
  print(dict[x])
```

Which returns

```
[{'truePos': 0}, {'falseNeg': 0}, {'falsePos': 0}, {'precision': 0}, 'recall', 'f1']
```

Now I cannot access and change the {"truePos": 0}.
(I want to for example, increment the value by 1 each time

What is the right way to do this in python2.7?
Thanks very much

I added the full Dict in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/FDT69dhE)

Answer (score 0):

Got it. 
The problem was that the first element had the length of 0

So I could not go deeper with

```
print(annotations[intent][0])
```